# What would be the best table design for paid subscription site?

Tags: database-design, paypal-subscriptions

my site would offer paid monthly subscription access and I was trying to contemplate the best way to set up my tables. Users can opt to pay by paypal if they wish to upgrade to premium services. I'm assuming that should a user choose to discontinue with the services their account would be restricted to a limited free access version.

I'm thinking that can I maintain this in a single table as the user details i.e:

```
USERS
ID| NAME| MEMBERSHIP_TYPE| LAST_PAYMENT_DATE| ACTIVE_TILL| TRANSACTION_ID
```

Of do I need to separate it into two different tables

```
USERS
ID| NAME

MEMBERSHIPS
USER_ID|MEMBERSHIP_TYPE|LAST_PAYMENT_DATE|ACTIVE_TILL|TRANSACTION_ID
```

And store the history of payments in a third table. I would be using recurring billing here.

Comment: Putting it into separate tables will make it more scalable for future uses such as if a user would like to sign up for multiple membership tiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to segregate payment transactions from your user list because you will want to be able to see the history of renewals.  You might have users that pay, request a refund, pay again, have their membership expire, and then renew - and so forth.  Without keeping a transaction table that maintains the history of this activity, you could find yourself being unable to untangle a customer service or accounting problem.

Assuming you only have one kind of paid membership (which may not be a future-safe assumption) and assuming you put the proper procedural controls in place, like using stored procs or triggers to synchronize data within transactional wrappers, you could denormalize membership type and active until date in your USERS table.  This type of redundancy might help your operational performance but it is also potentially very risky if you allow the redundant data to get out of sync.  I'd recommend trying it without the redundancy and then see if you have a practical performance issue before resorting to using denormalized fields in USERS.